# Trying to send an Error Object per Axois POST request, getting an empty Object on the Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, post, axios

Hello guys im building an Logging Microservice for frontend Errors.
So i want to see all Erros in my logs like this

```
catch(err){
 sendToLogs({message: 'Could not read input', error: err})
}
```

then

```
sendToLogger: (payload) => {
try {

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'config.loggingUrl',
  data: payload,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});

  }
} catch (err) {
}}
```

But on the Logging server the objects looks like

```
{message: 'Could not read input', error: {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be debug code. Have many reason, maybe variable `payload` is undefiend

Comment: i put a console.log right befor the post request and the payload object looks fine

Comment: maybe error in function axiosPostRequest, you can check input for function